# position:absolute and overflow:auto prevent number input scroll

Tags: css, html

I've encountered a problem when using a html5 number input inside a div with `position: absolute; overflow: auto` on Chromium Version 23.0.1271.64 (165188)

Normally scrolling the mouse wheel on a focused number input increments and decrements the value in the field. But inside a `div` with `position: absolute; overflow: auto`, the `div` contents just scroll unless there is nowhere to scroll.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9M9nx/7/

Is there a way to always let the input element receive the scroll event?

Comment: What browser are you using? The latest opera works as expected.

Comment: Using Chromium Version 23.0.1271.64 (165188) (updated question)

Comment: I filed a bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162025

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to hack this one. This hack works:

http://jsfiddle.net/9M9nx/12/

Here I've used jQuery to change the overflow property of the scrolling parent, based on the focus and blur events on the number input.

```
$('.scroller input[type=number]').focus(function(){
    $(this).closest('.scroller').css('overflow','hidden');
});

$('.scroller input[type=number]').blur(function(){
    $(this).closest('.scroller').css('overflow','auto');
});​
```